# What's the best way to index a text array with large text?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have some arbitrarily-sized text in a text array, and I would like to index it for `contains`  lookups.

It looks like the text in the array is too large for a traditional index.

This is also quite a large table - it has a few billion rows.

Using a standard GIN index gives me the error:

```
ERROR:  index row size 6648 exceeds maximum 2712 for index "index"
```

After looking it up, it looks like GIN defaults to using BTREE which is probably not the right thing to use for these types of huge columns.

What's a good alternate index I can use without having to resort to complex type conversion? (A simple one could do).

Comment: Can you please show the minimum relevant DDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not index the strings, but hashes thereof. For that, create a function like

```
CREATE FUNCTION hashtestarray(text[]) RETURNS integer[]
IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE
BEGIN ATOMIC
   SELECT array_agg(hashtext(t)) FROM unnest($1) AS a(t);
END;
```

That applies the `text` hash function to each element of the array.

Then index like

```
CREATE INDEX ON tab USING gin (hashtestarray(arraycol));
```

and search like

```
SELECT ... FROM tab
WHERE hashtestarray(arraycol) @> hashtext('searchstring')
  AND arraycol @> 'searchstring':
```

The first condition can use the index, and the second condition will remove false positives.